# How does R handle ordinal predictors in lm()?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

As I understand it, when you fit a linear model in R using a nominal predictor, R essentially uses dummy 1/0 variables for each level (except the reference level), and then giving a regular old coefficient for each of these variables. What does it do for *ordinal* predictors? It gives me estimated coefficients for each level, so it's not just treating the ranks as a numerical predictor. How do I properly interpret output like this?

```
cars.data <- mtcars[,1:3]
cars.data$cyl.ord <- ordered(cars.data$cyl)
lm(mpg ~ disp + cyl.ord, data = cars.data)
```

> ```
> Call:  
> lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + cyl.ord)  
>
> Coefficients:  
> (Intercept)         disp    cyl.ord.L    cyl.ord.Q  
>    26.34212     -0.02731     -3.38852      1.95127
> ```

I originally assumed that I could use the coefficients from the ordinal variable the same way I would if it were an unordered categorical, but `predict.lm(ord.model, newdata = data.frame("disp" = 150, "cyl.ord" = "6"))` gives 20.65263, while `26.34212378 -0.02730864*150 -3.38851642` gives only 18.85731, so that can't be it. (I tried +1.95127 and +0 in place of -3.38852 in case I was just mixed up about what order they were listed in, but no dice.) I couldn't find anything in the documentation for `order()` or `lm()`, online, or in any of my books.

How does R deal with ordinal predictors mathematically, and how should I deal with the output?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that transforming a factor variable into an ordinal factor variable changes the default contrast from "contr.treatment" to "contr.poly"

```
# make cyl a factor
cars.data$cyl <- factor(cars.data$cyl)
```

Now, consider the outputs of `lm` with "contr.treatment" and "contr.poly"

```
lm(mpg ~ disp + cyl.ord, data=cars.data)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + cyl.ord, data = cars.data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp    cyl.ord.L    cyl.ord.Q  
   26.34212     -0.02731     -3.38852      1.95127  

lm(mpg ~ disp + cyl, data=cars.data,
   contrasts=list(cyl="contr.poly"))

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + cyl, data = cars.data,
   contrasts=list(cyl = "contr.poly"))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp        cyl.L        cyl.Q  
   26.34212     -0.02731     -3.38852      1.95127
```

Sor the ordered factor uses "contr.poly" as the default contrast and we can get the same results from an unordered factor. Now, consider the unordered factor.

```
lm(mpg ~ disp + cyl, data=cars.data)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + cyl, data = cars.data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp         cyl6         cyl8  
   29.53477     -0.02731     -4.78585     -4.79209  

lm(mpg ~ disp + cyl.ord, data=cars.data, contrasts=list(cyl.ord="contr.treatment"))

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + cyl.ord, data = cars.data,
   contrasts=list(cyl.ord="contr.treatment"))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp     cyl.ord6     cyl.ord8  
   29.53477     -0.02731     -4.78585     -4.79209
```

So, an unordered factor variable uses "contr.treatment" by default and we can get the same results from an ordered factor by explicitly asking for it.

But let's take a closer look at the model matrices that are used in the regressions.

```
# Show model matrix
model.matrix(mpg ~ disp + cyl, data=cars.data)
                    (Intercept)  disp cyl6 cyl8
Mazda RX4                     1 160.0    1    0
Mazda RX4 Wag                 1 160.0    1    0
Datsun 710                    1 108.0    0    0
...
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2 2
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$cyl
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Now, use "contr.poly" as contrast

```
model.matrix(mpg ~ disp + cyl, data=cars.data, contrasts.arg=list(cyl="contr.poly"))
                    (Intercept)  disp         cyl.L      cyl.Q
Mazda RX4                     1 160.0 -9.073800e-17 -0.8164966
Mazda RX4 Wag                 1 160.0 -9.073800e-17 -0.8164966
Datsun 710                    1 108.0 -7.071068e-01  0.4082483
...
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2 2
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$cyl
[1] "contr.poly"
```

Next, check out cyl.ord in place of cyl

```
model.matrix(mpg ~ disp + cyl.ord, data=cars.data)
                    (Intercept)  disp     cyl.ord.L  cyl.ord.Q
Mazda RX4                     1 160.0 -9.073800e-17 -0.8164966
Mazda RX4 Wag                 1 160.0 -9.073800e-17 -0.8164966
Datsun 710                    1 108.0 -7.071068e-01  0.4082483
...
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2 2
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$cyl.ord
[1] "contr.poly"
```

The final two matrices have identical entries, so the use of "contr.poly" appears to explain the initial discrepencies. To learn more about contrasts, you can take a look at `?contrasts`.

Comment: Now I discover that I don't understand contrasts, but that's a different question (probably better suited for CV). Thank you!